# Firebase hosting : headers not taking effect (COEP and COOP http headers)

Tags: firebase, http-headers, firebase-hosting, sharedarraybuffer

I want to set the headers
`Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp` and `Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin` so I can enable `SharedArrayBuffer`, so I can use https://github.com/ffmpegwasm/ffmpeg.wasm

I have set these in `firebase.json`, however `console.log(crossOriginIsolated)` yields `false`,
and any attempt to use FFmpeg errors with `SharedArrayBuffer is not defined`.
This occurs with both the emulator and the deployed site.

I'm loading `ffmpegwasm` from jsdeliver with `<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@ffmpeg/ffmpeg@0.10.1/dist/ffmpeg.min.js" crossorigin="true"></script>`

Here's my complete `firebase.json` (just a simple demo project), with headers at the bottom:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  },
  "headers": [
    {
      "source": "**",
      "headers": [
        {
          "key": "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy",
          "value": "require-corp"
        },
        {
          "key": "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy",
          "value": "same-origin"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve the issue by changing the `"source": "**"` part to `"regex": "/.*"`. You could try different patterns to apply the header to the exact page paths you want to modify.